# Objective C - Core Data and setting up relationships?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When linking 2 NSManagedObjects in code, is it required to link them both ways as follow?

Or is it enough to link only 1 of them to another?

The problem is that sometimes my first object loses the pointer to the second object, and I'm trying to find out why this is happening.

```
// Initialize firstObject
// Initialize secondObject
// Objects have 1 to 1 relationship
firstObject.secondObject = secondObject;
secondObject.firstObject = firstObject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have linked the relationship both ways in the *data model*, then you do not need to write both these lines in your code. Just writing `firstObject.secondObject = secondObject;` should be enough to link it both ways.